# Как правильно организовать валидацию в mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, javascript

Имеется вот такая схема модели пользователей в mongoose (она ниже), мне необходимо для каждого поля (username, email, etc.) назначить валидатор через регулярные выражения, и, при вызове метода save() экземпляра модели, узнать какие поля невалидны. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это правильно и наиболее просто сделать?

```
var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
},
email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    lowercase: true
},
hashedPassword: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
salt: {
    type: String,
    required: true
}});
```

Comment: [Validation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html)

> * If an error occurs, your [Model#save](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-save) callback receives it
> * Strings have enum and [match](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schema_string_SchemaString-match) validators.

Answer (score 1):

[Дока по валидации Mongoose](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-validate).
Примеры кода:

```html
// make sure every value is equal to "something"
function validator (val) {
  return val == 'something';
}
new Schema({ name: { type: String, validate: validator }});
```

```html
    // with a custom error message

    var custom = [validator, 'Uh oh, {PATH} does not equal "something".']
    new Schema({ name: { type: String, validate: custom }});
```

```html
    // adding many validators at a time

    var many = [
        { validator: validator, msg: 'uh oh' }
      , { validator: anotherValidator, msg: 'failed' }
    ]
    new Schema({ name: { type: String, validate: many }});
```

```html
    // or utilizing SchemaType methods directly:

    var schema = new Schema({ name: 'string' });
    schema.path('name').validate(validator, 'validation of `{PATH}` failed with value `{VALUE}`');
```